# c# async await strange warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

i'm new to async programming, i get the below warning in this method, does somebody knows why this happens? Thank you very much.

```
   public async Task<List<T1>> StartSearchAsync()
    {
        ....other code

        searchRequests.ForEach(async s => {
            products.AddRange(await SinglePageSearch(s));
        });

        return products;
    }
```

> warning CS1998: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run
> synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await
> non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work
> on a background thread.

Comment: Remove `async`. It's *only*  used to enable you to `await`  methods in that particular method (`StartSearchAsync()`) . You are using `await` in the delegate passed to `ForEach`.

Comment: Please note that your code is likely broken down if you're using `List<T>.ForEach`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `await` is within a lambda expression, which is another function entirely to your `StartSearchAsync` method.

In fact you should not be passing an `async` delegate to `List<T>.ForEach`, as that converts the delegate to `async void`, which is undesirable because the calling method cannot wait for the delegates to complete.

A better option would be to use `Enumerable.Select`, in combination with `Task.WhenAll`:

```
public async Task<List<T1>> StartSearchAsync()
{
    ....other code
    
    var tasks = searchRequests.Select(SinglePageSearch);
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    foreach (result in results) products.AddRange(result);

    return products;
}
```

Using this approach, `Task.WhenAll` enumerates the `Task`s generated by `Select`, and creates another `Task` that completes when each `SinglePageSearch` has completed.

Now `StartSearchAsync` can `await` their completion.

And if `products` is simply an empty list being used to amalgamate the results, you can simplify further:

```
public async Task<List<T1>> StartSearchAsync()
{
    ....other code
    
    var results = await Task.WhenAll(searchRequests.Select(SinglePageSearch));

    return results.SelectMany(x => x).ToList();
}
```

Comment: i accepted only now your answer because i'm new to active stackoverflow posts. Thanks a lot, your answer was precious Johnatan!

Answer (score 1):

The compiler tells you that you can safely remove the `async` keyword from the method signature since you are not using the `await` keyword *directly* inside the `StartSearchAsync()` method.

You are indeed using `await` in the delegate that you pass for `ForEach` but this doesn't affect the compilation of the `StartSearchAsync()` method.

The `async` keyword is only used to enable you to `await` methods in the method or delegate that you mark as `async`.

Comment: "_you can safely remove the `async` keyword from the method signature_" it's anything but safe; nothing is waiting for the `Task`s being generated with `ForEach` to complete.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: `List<T>.ForEach` is synchronous and marking the method which calls it as `async` makes no sense at all unless you are actually using `await` inside the method. That's what the warning is all about. Are you saying that the compiler is wrong or what's your point?

Comment: @mm8 The compiler is correct, but simply removing the `async` keyword is not the right approach. That would likely result in `products` being returned before each `SinglePageSearch` has completed. The problem is that `List<T>.ForEach` shouldn't be used with an `async` delegate because, as you say, it is synchronous.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: That's indeed true but the actual implementation is not really related to the actual question being asked. Also note that method is called *Start*Search.

Comment: @mm8 "StartSearch" looks like poor nomenclature to me, based on the implementation: `products` is being returned which suggests that the method should run the complete search. And whilst you have answered the question _directly_, telling the OP to simply remove `async` is poor advice considering they are "new to async programming".

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: I don't give any advice here. I answered the actual question.